# Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute) with the same id "10" already exist

Tags: attributes, customer-address

I added two lines to `eav_attribute_label` that look like this:

```
attribute_id: 10,
store_id: 1
value: Address Number

attribute_id: 10,
store_id: 3
value: Address Number
```

This was an attempt to change the label of the `lastname` attribute in the `customer_address` entity type. This works fine in the front-end, and in form validation errors, etc.

However, now when I try to add a new address during checkout, I get this:

```
Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute) with the same id "10" already exist

#0 \lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(576): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute))
#1 \lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#2 \app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Form.php(263): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#3 \app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Form.php(360): Mage_Eav_Model_Form->getAttributes()
#4 \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php(541): Mage_Eav_Model_Form->extractData(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 \app\code\local\Forix\Custom\Model\Checkout\Type\Onepage.php(14): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveShipping(Array, '')
[...]
```

Any idea why this would act like I'm trying to create a new attribute, just because I changed the label of that attribute in the database? (The same database approach works for `catalog_product` attributes.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you got this fixed or not, but I had a duplicate set of labels for my attribute ID in the `eav_attribute_label` table, which was causing this exception:

```
mysql> select * from eav_attribute_label where attribute_id = 26;
+--------------------+--------------+----------+--------+
| attribute_label_id | attribute_id | store_id | value  |
+--------------------+--------------+----------+--------+
|                 49 |           26 |        1 | Suburb |
|                 50 |           26 |        2 | Suburb |
|                 51 |           26 |        3 | Town   |
|                 64 |           26 |        1 | Suburb | <----
|                 65 |           26 |        2 | Suburb | <---- Duplicates!
|                 70 |           26 |        3 | Town   | <----
+--------------------+--------------+----------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Removing the duplicated set fixed my issue.